# How to customize C# .NET Framework Manifest without Visual Studio

Tags: rider

I primarily use JetBrains Rider, which appears to lack the option to add a manifest (though my installation of Visual Studio mysteriously lacks "Application Manifest" under the "Add Item" menu anyhow).

So, I created `app.manifest` and filled it with the desired XML (in my case, it's a vanilla manifest with the classic `<requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false"/>`)... *but  it didn't work.*

I Changed Build Action to EmbeddedResource... *but it still didn't work*.

I renamed the file to `sandbox.exe.manifest`... *still nothing!*

If I open the exe in a text editor, I see two manifests - mine, and the default.

**What step am I missing?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to specify manifest file name in the project file. Open corresponding csproj file (`Solution Explorer -> select your project -> F4 \ Edit sources`) and add the next line to the global properties group :

```
<ApplicationManifest>app.manifest</ApplicationManifest>
```

For more information you can read this question:

[How can I embed an configuration-specific manifest file in my c# app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6767999/how-can-i-embed-an-configuration-specific-manifest-file-in-my-c-sharp-app)